# How to make span appear on each end of a TD

Tags: html, css

```html
<table width="200pxpx" bgcolor="#00FF00">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span align="left">1</span>
      <span align="right">2</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I would like to achieve is that 1 appears at the left end and 2 appears at the other end.

So in the script, 1 and 2 both show up at the left end of the TD.

I've also tried to add "align" attribute to make it happen but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the css-style `float:right`.

```html
<table style="width:200px; background-color:#00FF00;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span style="float:left;">1</span>
      <span style="float:right;">2</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Edit**: It's also better to use `style` for the other styling of your table (this is HTML5 standard I believe)

Comment: It's even better to use a CSS class name and a separate .css file to contain the rules (that's the HTML5 standard too :)).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [float](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp).

```html
<table width="200pxpx" bgcolor="#00FF00">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span style="float:left;">1</span>
      <span style="float:right;">2</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```